# Removing unused elements in user model

Tags: strongloop

In Strongloop, I want to extend the user model, but there are some fields I don't need:

```
username
credentials
verificationToken
```

When I create my database, I do not want to create columns for these useless fields.  What is the best way around this?

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there is an open issue: [A better way for customizing built-in models](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/397)

If you still want it: the work around is to first update the **/node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.json**, deleting the not required fields as:

```
{
  "name": "User",
  "properties": {
    "realm": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "emailVerified": "boolean",
    "status": "string",
    "created": "date",
    "lastUpdated": "date"
  },
  "hidden": ["password"],
  "acls": [
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "deleteById"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "login"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "logout"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findById"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "updateAttributes"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "confirm"
    },
    {
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "resetPassword",
      "accessType": "EXECUTE"
    }
  ],
  "relations": {
    "accessTokens": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "AccessToken",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "options": {
        "disableInclude": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note: I have also deleted challenges as it is now deprecated.**

Then you can extend it. For sql databases, you can create corresponding tables as in the **model.json**